# gfortran 8.2.1 produces large object files

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran

I tested a simple piece of fortran code,

```
       MODULE Mytest
             TYPE MY_DATA
                 SEQUENCE
                 integer :: A(1000, 1000)
                 REAL :: B(1000, 1000)
             END TYPE MY_DATA
      END MODULE Mytest
```

Compiled using gfortran. In the case of
gcc version 8.2.1 20180905 (Red Hat 8.2.1-3) (GCC) 
The generated object file size is 8001824 bytes and .mod is 1009 bytes. 
However when I tried gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC)
The generated object file size is only 936 bytes, and .mod is 1439 bytes.

Looks like the size of user-defined type is added to the object file in the case of gcc 8.2.1. 
I am new to the fortran, not sure what is going on. Is it possible to reduce the size of object file in gcc 8.2.1? Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You could compile with `-Os` flag to reduce size [ref](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). It somewhat helps in my case (gfortran-7.4.0).

Comment: @jcerar Thanks. I have tried and found not much difference. The -std=f95 does reduce significantly the file size. I am not sure if it is related to the changes in fortran 2003 and 2008.